# How to create a file that write the result of multiplication of two 2-D arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, io, console, try-catch

I have read a question that asks to write a program that does the following:

Read from two files two different matrices. One is 3x4 matrix and the other is 4x3.

Write in a file the result of the multiplication of these two matrices.

I initialized the needed arrays as follows:

```
int [][] m1 = new int [3][4];
int [][] m2 = new int [4][3];
int [][] m3 = new int [3][3];
```

and I wrote the needed code to open the two input files

```
Scanner input1 = null;
Scanner input2 = null;

PrinWriter output = null;

// first file
try {
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("file1.txt"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("The file cannot be open");
}

// second file
try {
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("file2.txt"));
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("The File Cannot be open");
}
```

But then I couldn't deal with the try & catch thing and how to read the two files' contents that I need to manipulate in order to write them in the result file

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't deal with the try-catch thing? Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: Exception is a pretty abstract exception for IO you need IOException. if you get an Exception but don't know the details, try printing the stack trace: e.printStackTrace();

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the File IO inside the try/catch but what you are probably missing is that as you read values from the file you can populate the arrays that should be defined outside the scope of the try/catch.

```
int[][] array1 = ...;
int[][] array2 = ...;

 try{
     // read file 1 and populate array 1
 catch(IOException e){
     // log failure here, possibly exit application
 }
 try{
     // read file 2 and populate array 2
 catch(IOException e){
     // log failure here, possibly exit application
 }

  // do array arithmetic

 try{
     // write output file file
 catch(IOException e){
     // log failure here, possibly exit application
 }
```